# Resampling on non-time related buckets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Say I have a df looking like this:

```
    price   quantity
0   100     20
1   102     31
2   105     25
3   99      40
4   104     10
5   103     20
6   101     55
```

There are no time intervals here. I need to calculate a Volume Weighted Average Price for every 50 items in quantity. Every row (index) in the output would represent 50 units (as opposed to say 5-min intervals), the output column would be the volume weighted price.

Any neat way to do this using pandas, or numpy for that matter?? I tried using a loop splitting every row into one item prices and  them group them like this:

```
def grouper(n, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
       chunk = tuple(itertools.islice(it, n))
       if not chunk:
           return
       yield chunk
```

But it takes for ever and I run out of memory.. The df is a few million rows.

**EDIT:**
The output I want to see based on the above is:

```
     vwap
0    101.20
1    102.12
2    103.36
3    101.00
```

Each 50 items gets a new average price.

Comment: Does [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) do what you need?

Comment: Can you elaborate pls?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do an average of every 50 items, correct? I wasn't sure if that's a rolling 50 items or each 50 items gets a new average. If it's the former, it seems like you could use `rolling` to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Each 50 items gets a new average..

Comment: How do we run `grouper` on the given sample `df`? Not every programmer out there might be good with pandas :)

Comment: Also, could you show the manual computations involved to get the 4 elements of the expected output for the sample?

Comment: I calculated the expected outcome manually in Excel..

Comment: .. Show us that?

Comment: I think the correct result for the example should be `101.20, 102.06, 101.76, 101.00` ? So not grouping by every 50 rows in the input, but by every 50 of accumulated `quantity`.

Comment: OK. I get it now. I completely misread the problem. I should delete my answer since it isn't a correct solution.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right, thanks for giving in a shot anyway.

Comment: Are you certain about the outcomes you expect from the small example you provided. I agree with @user7138814 that the results should be `101.20 , 102.06, 101.76, 101.00`. I calculated it on a spreadsheet too.

Comment: How would you do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struck out on my first at-bat facing this problem. Here's my next plate appearance. Hopefully I can put the ball in play and score a run.

First, let's address some of the comments related to the expected outcome of this effort. The OP posted what he thought the results should be using the small sample data he provided. However, @user7138814 and I both came up with the same outcome that differed from the OP's. Let me explain how I believe the weighted average of exactly 50 units should be calculated using the OP's example. I'll use this worksheet as an illustration.

[image]

The first 2 columns (A and B) are the original values given by the OP. Given those values, the goal is to calculate a weighted average for each block of exactly 50 units. Unfortunately, the quantities are not evenly divisible by 50. Columns C and D represent how to create even blocks of 50 units by subdividing the original quantities as needed. The yellow shaded areas show how the original quantity was subdivided and each of the green bounded cells sum to exactly 50 units. Once 50 units are determined the weighted average can be calculated in column E. As you can see, the values in E match what @user7138814 posted in his comment, so I think we agree on the methodology.

---

After much trial and error the final solution is a function that operates on the numpy arrays of the underlying price and quantity series. The function is further optimized using Numba decorator to jit-compile the Python code into machine-level code. On my laptop, it processed a 3 million row arrays in a second.

Here's the function.

```
@numba.jit
def vwap50_jit(price_col, quantity_col):
    n_rows = len(price_col)
    assert len(price_col) == len(quantity_col)

    qty_cumdif = 50  # cum difference of quantity to track when 50 units are reached
    pq = 0.0  # cumsum of price * quantity
    vwap50 = []  # list of weighted averages
    for i in range(n_rows):
        price, qty = price_col[i], quantity_col[i]

        # if current qty will cause more than 50 units
        # divide the units
        if qty_cumdif < qty:
            pq += qty_cumdif * price
            # at this point, 50 units accumulated. calculate average.
            vwap50.append(pq / 50)
            qty -= qty_cumdif
            # continue dividing
            while qty >= 50:
                qty -= 50
                vwap50.append(price)
            # remaining qty and pq become starting
            # values for next group of 50
            qty_cumdif = 50 - qty
            pq = qty * price
        # process price, qty pair as-is
        else:
            qty_cumdif -= qty
            pq += qty * price
    return np.array(vwap50)
```

Results of processing the OP's sample data.

```
Out[6]: 
   price  quantity
0    100        20
1    102        31
2    105        25
3     99        40
4    104        10
5    103        20
6    101        55

vwap50_jit(df.price.values, df.quantity.values)
Out[7]: array([101.2 , 102.06, 101.76, 101.  ])
```

Notice that I use the `.values` method to pass the numpy arrays of the pandas series. That's one of the requirements of using numba. Numba is numpy-aware and doesn't work on pandas objects.

It performs pretty well on 3 million row arrays, creating an output array of 2.25 million weighted averages.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.random.randint(95, 150, 3000000),
                  'quantity': np.random.randint(1, 75, 3000000)})


%timeit vwap50_jit(df.price.values, df.quantity.values)
154 ms ± 4.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

vwap = vwap50_jit(df.price.values, df.quantity.values)

vwap.shape
Out[11]: (2250037,)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I really appreciate all the work put into this. Not only have you given a great solution/function but also using numba speed things up which is of essence to me! Sorry about the miscalcs in the output sample. tnx vm

Comment: It was a fun challenge.